# DrawEventArgs GraphicsDevice Missing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, xna

I have an application written in c#, .NET 4 & silverlight 5 & XNA Frameworks, in VS 2010/Windows7pro.
When trying to use the System.Windows.Control.DrawEventArgs class to draw a scene (scene.Draw( e.GraphicsDevice)) there should be an GraphicsDevice object available but there is not.

Have I missed something?

Comment: No, it has a Graphics property. Sounds to me you are mixing up namespaces.  GraphicsDevice is XNA, Graphics is Silverlight.

Comment: Can you show your event handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/238255.aspx/1/10?Re+SL5+RC+Errors+when+going+from+beta+to+RC) which solved the same problem of mine.

Answer (score -1):

from [David Catuhe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/09/01/silverlight-5-rc-what-s-new-in-the-3d-world.aspx)'s blog

> The device is no longer handled by the DrawEventArgs class. It is now available on GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.